# Garbled text in tmux menus

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, tmux, escape-characters, terminal-multiplexer

I am trying to use the [st terminal](http://st.suckless.org), but after starting tmux (or screen) in a remote ssh session, the text becomes [all garbled](http://imgbin.me/view/PRHOHGYN). Exiting tmux/screen makes text normal again.

Now, I have found that this is due to [the alternate character set](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/alternate_charset/) becoming active, and echoing ^N fixes things.
In the shell.

Inside tmux, though, [apparently](http://imgbin.me/view/SOGBUCQF) the alternate character set remains active.

Since tmux uses a pseudo-terminal for itself, I tried echoing ^N to this particular device, hoping this would reset the character set for tmux too, but it didn't work.

Any idea how to reset the character set for tmux itself?

Comment: Does the problem go away if you do the following? 1) Suspend/detach, 2) Run `printf '\017';tput rmacs` in the shell running directly under *st*, 3) Resume/attach — BTW, you probably want to use ^O (C-o) to get back to the normal character set (in VT-100-like terminals ^N **starts** the alternate set).

Comment: Executing the above sequence didn't change anything.
You are correct that ^N starts (shifts in to) and ^O ends (shifts out of) the alternate character set, but I meant ^N when I said it in the question. It is precisely ^N that brings things back to normal. I don't know why.

Comment: Just found out that once the problem has occurred remotely, even locally started tmux gives the same behavior. Before triggering the issue remotely, local tmux is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a terminfo issue.

I was trying to fool tmux into believing that TERM=screen-256color, because there were no st terminfo entries on the remote machines I use.

Copying the st-256color terminfo to the remote machine did it.

Not convenient when you need to access various remote hosts, but hopefully st will become more popular and distributions will have its terminfos by default.